# When coding a Wordpress theme, where does the theme (i.e. the presentation) end and the plugin (i.e. the functionality) begin?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

The best guideline I have seen for what should be in a theme is to put "functionality" in a plugin.

I am looking at adding more "premium features" like jQuery image sliders. This requires a back-end user interface for selecting featured content to slide. Is this presentation?

How about shortcodes? A shortcode is a simple hook that enables you to call a PHP function by adding something such as [shortcode] to a post or page. I see this in themes all the time. Is it presentation?

I am unable to sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

Keep most of the heavy lifting in your functions.php file and you should be fine. But don't be afraid to add functionality to your other theme files since PHP and WordPress rely heavily on the integration of function and presentation.

The functions.php file of your theme is basically that theme's "plugins." There is really no difference between what you can do with functions.php and what you can do with a plugin.

Reasons to create a plugin instead of embedding it into the functions.php file include wanting re-usability in other themes, or if the Theme didn't necessarily depend on the functionality and disabling the plugin was something you wanted to have as an option.

Reasons to use the functions.php instead of plugins include your themes dependency on the functionality to aide the presentation in some manner and therefore the theme would look wrong without it.